# Android Error opening trace file

Tags: android

I am creating simple `Hello World` default project and when run get the follow error.

```
04-07 06:27:08.369: D/dalvikvm(959): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-07 06:34:05.429: E/Trace(1132): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-07 06:34:06.059: D/gralloc_goldfish(1132): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

I almost read all threads on here but not find the solution. 

Is any get the solution?

Comment: please post error log trace